# Python - CSV Reader List Comprehension

Tags: python, list, csv, list-comprehension

I am trying to read the columns in a file efficiently using CSV reader. The code is:

```
import csv
csv.register_dialect('csvrd', delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)


with open('myfile.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,'csvrd')
    a0=[x[0] for x in reader]
    a1=[x[1] for x in reader]
```

I obtain the values in the first column, but a1 is empty. If I write a1 first, then a0 is empty.

I know a simple solution, inserting

```
reader=[x for x in reader]
```

But just curious about the reason. When you read an entry from the reader, is it removed?

A sample myfile.txt

```
c11 c21 c31
c21 c22 c32
```

Comment: `[x for x in reader]` can be written as `list(reader)`. Still, explicit `for` loop can be better: you iterate over your CSV file exactly one time and do whatever you want without any issues while your code tries to do it twice. It's possible to write same in list comprehension but comprehensions are not always more clean/pythonic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot loop over the `reader` more than once, not without rewinding the underlying file to the start again.

Don't do that, however; transpose the rows to columns using `zip(*reader)` instead:

```
a0, a1, a2 = zip(*reader)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import csv
>>> csv.register_dialect('csvrd', delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
>>> data = '''\
... c11\tc21\tc31
... c21\tc22\tc32
... '''
>>> reader = csv.reader(data.splitlines(True), 'csvrd')
>>> a0, a1, a2 = zip(*reader)
>>> a0
('c11', 'c21')
>>> a1
('c21', 'c22')
>>> a2
('c31', 'c32')
```

Answer (score 2):

`csv.reader` returns a generator. In order to read from a generator again, you will have to re-declare it. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained/231855#231855) has a detailed explanation on how Python's generators work.